# How to create a table inside mysql database via an android application?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm working on an android application that asks the user for number of classes under his/her wing and than create a list of those classes.

Now when the user will click on one of the class, it will ask the no. of students inside that class and then the user will enter the name of students.

So, internally it will create the list of tables with class names and than give a particular table required fields on the bases of number of students mentioned.

How can I achieve this? How can I create the tables from the application ?

I'm using PHP for connecting the database to the application.

Comment: You are asking a lot in the same time. Try to break your question into smaller pieces and don't forget to add code of parts you are having trouble with.

Comment: I just need a vauge idea about how can I create a table inside mysql via an android application using php as a backened.

Comment: We don't do vague ideas on Stack Overflow. Perhaps another site on the stack exchange network is a better fit.

Comment: "We don't do vague ideas on  stack overflow".Talking, as if your daddy owns stack overflow.

Comment: My daddy doesn't own Stack Overflow, but if you have read the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages, you'd know that as well.

Comment: You can achieve this by just writing all SQL stuffs for creating table inside your PHP service code and you have to pass the parameter from your Android Endpoint to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understand or your problem is to create a table with *PHP*?

You can simply connect to your database (just like you do when you connect to read data from a table) and use the connection to take this simple query:

```
CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

Obviously you will need to know a minimum of *MySQL* rules, so at least know the difference between an *INT* and a *VARCHAR*.
To start you could use the *INT* for the columns that will contain numerical values, while the *VARCHAR* for those that will contain alphanumeric values..

The number in round brackets indicates the maximum value in bytes that the record can contain ..

If you need anything else, please reply to me in the comments